# Mysql Query for comparing two tables' and inserting the matched in another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, say XYZ and ABC

```
XYZ 
| id|
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |


ABC 
| id| name |
| 3 | rocky|
| 4 | Alex |
```

Perform ---->

```
ALTER TABLE XYZ ADD COLUMN name VARCHAR(8);
```

Now I want to set the values of ABC table in XYZ,like:-

```
| id| name |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |
| 3 | rocky|
| 4 | Alex |
| 5 | null |
```

I want a single line query??

Comment: You cannot mix DDL and DML. 2 queries needed. But they may be executed as multi-query (in one statement on the client side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming id is a primary key:

```
REPLACE INTO XYZ SELECT * FROM ABC
```

If id isn't a primary key or a unique key, a multi-table update like:

```
update XYZ JOIN ABC USING (id) SET XYZ.name=ABC.name
```

ref: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=add5392d4cf2a55d9fdb88f52f866b6f)

Comment: It works Thanks ...Just curious!! how much efficient this query is if I have so many records? Also what if 'id' is not a primary key ?? what are queries then ??

Comment: Efficiency of large updates is fairly universal that innodb needs to keep a record of all the updates and then at a later time batch apply them. Provided it fits in the innodb_buffer_pool its generally ok.

Comment: And if id isn't indexed at all, it becomes slower hopefully obviously.